# "User was removed" statistics

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-accounts

I periodically lose points because a "user was removed." I've often thought, "Wait...what? The questions I answered recently were all benign, and there's no way that the OP would have gone ballistic, started spewing venom, and had their account deleted" (although I recognize that there are other reasons for removal as well).

I now realize that it could be that the OP may have simply asked a question or two, gotten answers, and decided to remove their account for some reason, that is, there might have been a **self**-removal rather than a **moderator**-removal. That seems OK, and I can live with the reputation loss, of course.

But it made me wonder: *Can someone with better search-abilities or permissions tell, for some recent month like September, what fraction of "user removed" events (in MSE) were self-removals and what fraction were moderator removals?*

What I'd really like, of course, is to figure out how to avoid spending time answering questions that will soon go away, but that's probably asking too much.

Comment: There are other reasons an account can be removed my mods, other than "the user going ballistic and spewing venom".  Sock puppet account? (to get around question limitations, or getting around a question ban for habitually asking low quality questions, etc.  Or the OP deleted it.  I'd suggest you keep to answering questions that are not PSQs or low quality questions; IIRC, you've answered many such questions.

Comment: I know there are other reasons, but I was still interested in the statistics.

Comment: I think that the only people who can reliably do that are CMs, and I don't see them making time for this sort of statistics which they may very well prefer to leave ambiguous in general.

Comment: Most user removals affecting you will have been self-removals. Of course every prolific answerer occasionally is hit by the removal of other people's sockpuppets (the typical sock does not exclusively vote for the puppeteer account), but these are comparatively rare. Most moderator-removed accounts are spammers or trolls, and those don't vote.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel --- that's really the answer I was looking for. Numbers would've been nice, but the overall picture is pretty clear.